# Mostrar un contenido mediante POO

Tags: php, poo

Estoy intentando comprender como funciona la Programación Orientada a Objetos y como ejercicio iba a intentar ha hacer una especie de videoclub empleando este concepto y no SQL.

La cuestión es que hice el código de a continuación y si no entendí mal. Yo hice lo siguiente,

1) Declaro la clase. En este caso pelicula.

2) Declaro las variables con las que voy a trabajar.

3) Declaro un método constructor para que inicialmente estas variables tengan un valor. En mi caso indefinido.

4) Defino ya cada película con su respectivo título, año... enlazadas al método constructor.

5) Muestro la película que yo quiera. (Posteriormente esto se haría con algún input de html).

```html
<?PHP

    class Pelicula{
        var $Titulo;        // Defino las propiedades que tendrán los objetos
        var $TituloOriginal;
        var $Anyo;
        var $Duracion;
        
        function Pelicula(){        // Declaro constructor. Es decir, el valor de las propiedades al iniciarse
            $this -> Titulo = "";   // Lo declaro como indefinido
            $this -> TituloOriginal = "";
            $this -> Anyo = "";
            $this -> Duracion = "";
        }
        
        function IJArcaPerdida(){
            $this -> Titulo = "Indiana Jones en busca del arca perdida";
            $this -> TituloOriginal = "Raiders of the lost ark";
            $this -> Anyo = "1981";
            $this -> Duracion = "115 min";
        }
        
        function IJTemploMaldito(){
            $this -> Titulo = "Indiana Jones y el templo maldito";
            $this -> TituloOriginal = "Indiana Jones and the Temple of Doom";
            $this -> Anyo = "1984";
            $this -> Duracion = "118 min";
        }
        
        echo IJTemploMaldito();
    }

?>
```

No consigo mostrarlo y he hecho pruebas, con echo, new... pero no se como se hace. Se que debe estar fatal pero es que no termino de entender el tema de `poo` y ya he consultado varios tutoriales y hilos...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La POO es un concepto bastante amplio que puedes ir estudiando en base a [esta guía completa](http://php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.php).

Una de las ventajas de programar clases es que éstas se pueden compartir en un entorno colaborativo, o sea, en una clase pueden intervenir varios programadores (pensemos en un programa amplio en el que intervienen varios programadores).

Por ello, una regla fundamental en la POO es **respetar una convención de nombres**, y respetar una cierta estructura que debería tener cada clase.

También podríamos hablar del **encapsulamiento**, del **poliformismo** y otros elementos que constituirían el núcleo de la POO.

Una clase representa generalmente una entidad completa de nuestro programa, y debe ser capaz de manejarla adecuadamente respetando los fundamentos de la POO.

Una clase `Pelicula` básica tendría la siguiente estructura:

```
   class Pelicula{
        private $Titulo;
        private $TituloOriginal;
        private $Anyo;
        private $Duracion;

       public function __construct($Titulo, $TituloOriginal, $Anyo, $Duracion){
            $this->Titulo = $Titulo;
            $this->TituloOriginal = $TituloOriginal;
            $this->Anyo = $Anyo;
            $this->Duracion = $Duracion;
       }

       public function getTitulo() {
          return $this->Titulo;
       }

       public function setTitulo($Titulo) {
          $this->Titulo=$Titulo;
       }       

       public function getTituloOriginal() {
          return $this->TituloOriginal;
       }       

       public function setTituloOriginalo($TituloOriginal) {
          $this->TituloOriginal=$titulo;
       }       

       public function getAnyo() {
          return $this->Anyo;
       }       

       public function setAnyo($Anyo) {
          $this->Anyo=$Anyo;
       }       

       public function getDuracion() {
          return $this->Duracion;
       }       

       public function setDuracion($Duracion) {
          $this->Duracion=$Duracion;
       }              

       public function toString() {
          return $this->Titulo. " ".$this->TituloOriginal." ".$this->Anyo." ".$this->Duracion;
       }              
   }
```

Vemos algunas cosas en esta clase:

1. Los miembros son declarados como `private`.  Una clase no debería permitir que sus miembros sean modificados directamente.
2. Cada miembro tiene dos tipo de accesores que son llamados `getters` y `setters`. Por convención de nombres estos métodos se llaman siempre `getMiembro` y `setMiembro`. Sería las únicas formas de acceder a los miembros de la clase, para obtener sus valores o para modificarlos.
3. La clase tendría también un método `toString` que devolvería una representación general del objeto.

Para probar la clase de más arriba:

```
/*Se crea una instancia del objeto*/
$unaPelicula=new Pelicula("Indiana Jons", "IJ Título Original", 2018, "2:42");

/*Obtener el Titulo, usando el getter*/
echo $unaPelicula->getTitulo();

/*Modificar el año, mediante el setter*/
$unaPelicula->setAnyo(2014);
```

Si `Anyo` fuese declarado como `public` en la clase, se podría hacer algo como esto:

```
$unaPelicula->Anyo=2017;
```

Estaríamos ante una violación flagrante de la **Encapsulación**, uno de los principios básicos de la POO.

Answer (score 6):

te comento un par de cosas

1.- La idea de la POO es modular así que no hace mucho sentido que tengas que declarar cada película dentro de la propia clase
2.- Ese último echo que pusiste ahí no va, pues la clase es una estructura genérica
3.- Las propiedades en este caso no llevan la palabra reservada `var`, lo que si llevan es su modificador de acceso como puede ser
 `public`
 `private`
 `protected`
4.- Los métodos deben indicar que son `publicos`, privados o `protegidos` igualmente
5.- No debes asignar de manera directa la equivalencia de valores y menos usar `echo` o `print` dentro de la clase ya que su finalidad como te digo solo es servir como una plantilla genérica; es en las instancias donde ya lo puedes hacer ya que con cada objeto nuevo creado los valores que pasaste en el constructor son creados
6.- Los constructores al menos en PHP son con `__construct` como te muestro en el ejemplo

Te dejo tu ejemplo adaptado a algunas de estas reglas para que lo sigas checando, saludos

```
<?php

    class Pelicula{
        // Defino las propiedades que tendrán los objetos
        public $Titulo;        
        public $TituloOriginal;
        public $Anio;
        public $Duracion;


        public function __construct($Titulo, $TituloOriginal, $Anio, $Duracion)
        {
            $this->Titulo = $Titulo;
            $this->TituloOriginal = $TituloOriginal;
            $this->Anio = $Anyo;
            $this->Duracion = $Duracion;

        }

        public function nuevaPelicula(){
            return  $this->Titulo.$this->TituloOriginal.$this->Anio.$this->Duracion;
        }
    }

    $obj = new Pelicula("titulo", "titulote", "2018", "123");
    echo $obj->nuevaPelicula();

//si necesitas declarar los valores de otra película, entonces creas una instancia nueva
    $obj2 = new Pelicula("titulo2", "titulito", "2017", "249");
    echo $obj2->nuevaPelicula();
```